# Quando não tem especificação de string com a classe configurado onde o Entity Framework criar as tabelas

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Criei um projeto novo usando Asp.Net MVC com EF, e não configurei no Web.config a propriedade de string de conexão com o mesmo nome da classe do Contexto : DbContext.

Rodei enable-migrations -> funcionou com sucesso

Rodei add-migration NomeMigration -> funcionou certinho

Rodei update-database -> funcionou com sucesso.

Porém não criou no banco que eu havia especificado no Web.config, e ao tentar executar o update-database retorno que está sem pendência a executar.

Queria entender nesse caso ele salva em que lugar essas informações?

Este é meu Web.config na parte de conexão.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conexao" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=bancoDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Minha classe Contexto

```
using System;

namespace AppWeb2.Models
{
    public class Mycontext : DbContext
    {      
        //Classes a ser mapeadas
        public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque seu projeto Web como Startup Project, veja se funciona.

Comment: Como está a sua classe `Contexto`?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta acrescentando a classe Contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde estão meus dados?

Por padrão o EF usa o LocalDb, se você não especificou para o construtor do DbContext qual era a conectionstring provavelmente ele fez isso.

[Por convenção](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx), o DbContext criar um banco de dados para você.

- Se uma instância local do SQL Express estiver disponível (instalada
  por padrão com o Visual Studio), o Code First criar o banco de
  dados nessa instância.
- Se o SQL Express não estiver disponível, o Code First tentará usar o
  LocalDb (instalado por padrão com o Visual Studio)